# Perfect word for the clicking sound which happens when you stretch your bones?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

What is the perfect word for the clicking sound which happens when you stretch your bones?

When chiropractors try to do adjustments, we can hear a clicking sound on the bones.

What is that sound called?

Comment: *[Cracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cracking_joints).*

Comment: It's called "cracking" or "popping," and it's your body trying to tell you to get out of the chiropractor's office before he does some real damage.

Comment: Is that true .. , I thought going to Chiropractors fixes your problems ..

Comment: Only if you believe that to be true.  A massage therapist will do wonders.

Comment: @deadrat At the risk of going off-topic, medical evidence [does not seem to support the hypothesis](https://dx.doi.org/10.3122%2Fjabfm.2011.02.100156) that joint cracking causes arthritis or other pathologies.

Comment: @MarchHo And of course, that's not my hypothesis.  Yes, there's no medical evidence that joint cracking is harmful.  The same can't be said about chiropracty.

Comment: Cracking, popping, creaking, crunching, grinding, and occasionally squeaking.  (Hard to tell whether the "groaning" is from the bones, the patient, or my readers, though.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This phenomenon is known either as "popping" or "cracking".

This [Scientific American article](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-makes-the-sound-when/) describes the cause of the popping and cracking sounds when joints are moved quickly.

> To understand what happens when you "crack" your knuckles, or any
>   other joint, first you need a little background about the nature of
>   the joints of the body. The type of joints that you can most easily
>   **"pop" or "crack"** are the diarthrodial joints. These are your most
>   typical joints. They consist of two bones that contact each other at
>   their cartilage surfaces; the cartilage surfaces are surrounded by a
>   joint capsule. Inside the joint capsule is a lubricant, known as
>   synovial fluid, which also serves as a source of nutrients for the
>   cells that maintain the joint cartilage. In addition, the synovial
>   fluid contains dissolved gases, including oxygen, nitrogen and carbon
>   dioxide.
>
> The cracking or popping sound is thought to be caused by the gases
>   rapidly coming out of solution, allowing the capsule to stretch a
>   little further. The stretching of the joint is soon thereafter limited
>   by the length of the capsule.

Comment: P.S.  Don't ever use the words "crack" or "pop" when speaking to a chiropractor - they are regarded as blasphemous:  "Help, Doc, I'm stuck - you gotta crack my neck!"  *"Are you telling me that you need an adjustment of your cervical subluxation?"*  (They'll do it every time...)